# I am getting this error A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. while syncing my project?

Tags: android, gradle

I have downloaded a project from github. And I am trying to run it but it fails to run and give me that error. Here is my gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    mplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

and here is the error message that I get every time I run

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method mplementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

and this is the link to the project that I am trying to run in my android studio

https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase

Comment: NO need to worry. I have figured it out where I made the mistake. There was the typo  mplementation in dependencies. show I have corrected it by adding i before mplementation (implementation).

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling mistake in your gradle file inside the first line in dependencies block.

```
dependencies {
       mplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
       ...
}
```

If you look at the error it says:  **Could not find method mplementation()**

Please change the `mplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'`
to  `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'`

**i.e.** **implementation** spelling is wrong.
Make the above change and re-sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

The anwer is already in the error. Theres an "i" missing in the first implementation.

```
    mplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

Needs to be changed to

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```